# What is typing discipline?

Tags: c#, terminology

Wikipedia talks about [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)) typing discipline:

> static, dynamic, strong, safe, nominative, partially inferred

What is typing discipline? What those terms mean and how they are related to the language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typing discipline on wikipedia refers to the type system used by C# (just try clicking the link, it will lead you to the [Type System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) article).

As for what they mean:

**static** - The types are determined at compile-time (the compiler wants to know the type before it runs)

**dynamic** - The types are determined at runtime (in C#, this is facilitated with the `dynamic` keyword introduced in C# 4.0)

**safe** - The language doesn't allow you to violate the type rules that it has. You can't put strings into a list of complex types for instance without a cast defined.

**strong** - Rather than poorly explain it, have a look at Eric Lippert's article on the topic [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/10/15/is-c-a-strongly-typed-or-a-weakly-typed-language/)

**nominative** - The name of the type is used to determine type equivalence (what this means is that two types with the same fields but different names are treated as different types)

**partially inferred** - The compiler can guess the type you are referring to during compile-time (this is the `var` keyword in c#, which allows you to not specify the type in your code, although it's still determined at compile-time in a static and strong way)